# How to eliminate the black border around picture in opencv?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, tesseract, image-preprocessing

[image: This is the picture]

I want to get rid of the black border around inorder to enhance ocr prediction. How to eliminate it? this is my code so far.

```
image = cv2.imread(filename)
cv2.resize(image,(416,416))
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_lp = cv2.resize(gray, (333, 75))
#img_gray_lp = cv2.cvtColor(img_lp, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, img_binary_lp = cv2.threshold(img_lp, 200, 255, 
cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
img_binary_lp = cv2.erode(img_binary_lp, (3,3))
img_binary_lp = cv2.dilate(img_binary_lp, (3,3))
cv2.floodFill(img_binary_lp, None, (0,0), 255)
LP_WIDTH = img_binary_lp.shape[0]
LP_HEIGHT = img_binary_lp.shape[1]

# Make borders white
img_binary_lp[0:3,:] = 255
img_binary_lp[:,0:3] = 255
img_binary_lp[72:75,:] = 255
img_binary_lp[:,330:333] = 255

#Estimations of character contours sizes of cropped license plates
dimensions = [LP_WIDTH/6,
                   LP_WIDTH/2,
                   LP_HEIGHT/10,
                   2*LP_HEIGHT/3]

plt.imshow(img_binary_lp, cmap='gray')
```

if i tried flood fill it removes certain initial letters in certain images like [image: this after flood fill which removes certain letters]

The original image of the above is [image: original image which removes certain letters in floodfill]

Comment: Flood fill with white at seed point `(0, 0)`. Assuming OpenCV for Python, and some grayscale image: `cv2.floodFill(img, None, (0, 0), 255)`. Won't get rid of the small black parts bottom right, but should be sufficient for further OCR, I guess.

Comment: @HansHirse I tried floodfill but it results in removing few initial letters in certain images.

Comment: Please provide the original input image.

Comment: @HansHirse I've added the original image

Comment: `cv2.floodFill(img_binary_lp, None, (4, 4), 255)` AFTER making the borders white.

Comment: still the output is same as before.

Comment: Which output? The image (show your updated code) - or the result of the later (and still not shown) OCR?

Comment: cv2.floodFill(img_binary_lp, None, (4, 4), 255) i've added this line after  cv2.floodFill(img_binary_lp, None, (0,0), 255) line in the above code. The output image is same it removes initial letters as shown above.

Comment: Remove `cv2.floodFill(img_binary_lp, None, (0, 0), 255)`, and add `cv2.floodFill(img_binary_lp, None, (4, 4), 255)` after `img_binary_lp[:,330:333] = 255`..... (I won't further support here.....)